# Does running Ubuntu on a Dell laptop sold with Windows void the warranty?

Tags: dell

If I run Ubuntu on a Dell laptop which was sold with Windows, will that void my warranty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it wont void the warranty. You can revert back to windows using the recovery partition or any other recovery media that was supplied with your laptop and your laptop will be back to the state where it was when you bought it. If you are new to Ubuntu and if your laptop comes with recovery partition (which most of laptops these days do) then make sure that you create recovery disks first before installing Ubuntu. Because sometimes people trash their harddisks while installing Linux and that can destroy your recovery partition. Even if you destroy the recovery partition and dont have the recovery disks, you can buy them from dell.

Comment: So I should put windows back on it before sending it for repair?

Comment: No, this shouldn't be a problem, since it is a hardware failure. There is no liability to use windows for warranty reasons. I sent my packard-bell (aka ACER) shipped with windows back for repair the power on/off button with Ubuntu installed. It was no problem at all.

Comment: I have a Dell Latitude, and removed the recovery partition.  When I got a hardware problem they asked me to restore from the recovery partition for some test and I said I had removed it because I installed a different OS.  They said it was no problem at all, because there is a BIOS self-diagnostic that tells them what they need to know.

Answer (score 4):

When you send a computer with ubuntu installed for repairs, when it had windows on it, they will take no responsability if they had to re-install windows and remove your ubuntu partition and your data (considering your disk was still ok).

My brother sent his computer for repair because is wifi wasn't working. He got a windows computer back...

Comment: they likely replaced his computer instead of repairing it, and of course will not take the time to clone your drive over. this applies to still having windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

They **Say no**, it will not be void but they will not be responsible for the software. most of the time they wipe everything and give you a new OS.

Here is the  thread from [Dell Website](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Warranty-Void-if-install-Linux/td-p/3236102),And here is also another thread specific for a  [Dell  laptop](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General/Installing-Ubuntu-16-04-on-Dell-Inspiron-13-7348/td-p/5151877)